# phpmyadmin query using multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Ill make it simple I have 2 tables in my database
1. Post
2. User

The columns inside the Post table are
`Post ID`
`User ID`
`Post Title`
`Post Content`

Then the columns in User table are
`User ID` - Connected to `Post.User ID`
`User Full Name`

Then I want to do now is to select the post posted by Juan Cruz(User.User Full Name). Help Please, I cannot find these question anywhere.

PS Sorry for my bad english.

EDIT: I will use this as my search module on my php/html project. So I need to know the post/s posted by Juan Cruz insted of User ID of Juan Cruz. Thanks Again

Comment: Take the `User ID` of Juan then use it when querying for the post

Comment: I've Edited the post, thanks Carl Jan.

Comment: Then use the search value to find a row in the `User` table. If you got a row, take its `User ID`.

Comment: This has a point, thanks Carl Jan I appreciated your comment. Will try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this might help:

```
SELECT
    p.post_id, p.user_id, p.post_title, p.post_content,
    u.user_fullname     
    // column name from two or more tables
    // eg: table_name.column_name
    // use p and u, because we already give temporary name for table post and user
FROM
    post p          // table 1: post refer as p (SQL aliases)
JOIN                // combine 2 column from two or more tables
    user u          // table 2: user refer as u (SQL aliases)
ON
    p.user_id = u.user_id   // key for joining the table, the ID should be the same
```

or you can use below code without aliases :

```
SELECT
    post.post_id, post.user_id, post.post_title, post.post_content,
    user.user_fullname
FROM
    post
JOIN
    user
ON
    post.user_id = user.user_id
```

Refer: [SQL JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **JOIN**.  This should be updated to use your column names.

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content, u.full_name FROM User AS u JOIN Post AS p ON (u.id = p.user_id);
```

Comment: This works, but I didn't get the logic of Join. I'm a Newbie in phpmyadmin. BTW, thanks for this..